# Wildcard tags unrolling issue

Tags: support, tags, search, wildcards

Searching for [`[status-*] text`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-*%5D%20text) doesn't unroll the tags in search input (top bar + page specific):

> [image: no-unroll]

Eliminating the [`text`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-*%5D) from the search query will unroll the tags in the top bar search input (page specific search input is not visible at all):

> [image: unroll]

Is there a reason for such a different behaviour?

Comment: @animuson, this is funny that this question has been closed as a duplicate of my own 2yo post. But despite of [status-bydesign] on the target question, there is no explanation the reason of such "design".